# Restraint/validation to not allow negative integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

What would be a way to not allow negative numbers for an integer column?

I thought maybe this would work, but it didn't:

```
validates_numericality_of :rolling_rank, :only_integer => true, :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0
```

> EDIT:

In context, there is a nightly cron that does a bunch of calculating, and uses `MyObject.decrement!(:rolling_rank, by = calculated_value)`. If the decrement *tries to go into the negative*, I want it to stop (and save) at zero.

Comment: not much difference, but try this.   `validates :rolling_rank,      numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }`

Comment: Your code looks correct. In what way did it not work? What happens when you do e.g. `MyModel.create!(rolling_rank: -1)` in the Rails console?

Comment: @Jordan I get `Validation failed: Rolling rank must be greater than or equal to 0`. The objects already exit though, I am updating my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [docs for `decrement!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-decrement-21) (emphasis mine):

> **decrement!**(attribute, by = 1)
>
> Wrapper around `decrement` that saves the record. This method differs from its non-bang version in that it passes through the attribute setter. ***Saving is not subjected to validation checks.*** Returns `true` if the record could be saved.

If this is what you want...

> If the decrement tries to go into the negative, I want it to stop (and save) at zero.

...then you don't want a validation.

I think the simplest solution is to override the `rolling_rank=` setter:

```
def rolling_rank=(value)
  value = 0 if value < 0
  super
end
```

Since `decrement!` "passes [the value] through the attribute setter," this will be invoked before the record is persisted.